# How to make swift native module in react native using cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, frameworks

I've been struggled to create a custom swift native module for react native. I wrote a bridge files to wrap the native module (which is in swift). This native module also has dependencies from `cocoapods`. Since  react native module that I am working on, has to be linked with native module (to clarify, react native module A has a native module dependency B which can be installed by cocoapods), I have to use something like B-Swift.h (created by Xcode) in the react native module for objective-c project. The problem is I cannot find a proper way to configure header file in this situation. I was able to properly link everything together with `carthage` though.

I would appreciate for any advices.